# In Facebook's privacy settings, what does the Other category mean?

Tags: privacy, facebook

I understand the other categories, but what does the 'Other' one mean. Who does it include?

[image]

Answer (score 10):

When editing your privacy settings, you can use the "Customize" option, which lets you choose your own settings for who can view it, e.g. Just certain networks you're in or just yourself. Those (and more) options are filed under "Other".